# No Git, não consigo fazer o Pull, dá ERROR 502

Tags: github, gitlab

Estou em um projeto e consigo mudar de Branch (Checkout), fazer o fetch, merge, mas o pull não consigo, retorna a mensagem

> fatal: unable to access '': The requested URL returned error: 502

Fiz vários testes e nada.

Comment: Deu ruim no servidor mano, qual você está usando? Coloque na sua pergunta a saída do comando `git remote show origin`. Provavelmente o 502 refere-se a um status do HTTP, o "Bad Gateway".

Comment: @Daniel Campanha, dá uma olhada [aqui](https://twitter.com/gitlabstatus/status/872124494214832129)

Comment: @rodorgas , o comando retorna " fatal: unable to access 'http://git@gitlab.bndes.net/cti-arquitetura/migrations.git/': The requested URL returned error: 502 ". E eu creio que o servidor não esteja ruim, porque eu consigo fazer o Push(prova de que há conexão).

Comment: A saída que você colocou aqui é de git pull é não de git remote, certo? Você pode ter em .git/config um servidor configurado para o pull e outro para o push, isso explicaria a diferença. Por favor inclua na pergunta a saída de `git remote -v`. Você poderia incluir tbm o próprio .git/config, mas remova as informações sensíveis antes de postar.

Comment: é @rodorgas, acabou que tiver que zerar e fazer o pull do meu colega de trabalho, funcionou aqui.. O problema anterior era fazer da "metade do caminho".. mas muito obrigado ! Espero que ajude outras pessoas por aqui também. ;)